# Adding a TestExecutionListener

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-test

I know that if I need to use a precise implementation `TestExecutionListener`, it will prevent the loading of the default TestExecutionListeners.
If my test class is like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({MyCustomTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-ApplicationContext.xml" })
public class CabinetMembershipServiceImplTest {
     ...
}
```

`MyCustomTestExecutionListener` will be the only loaded Listener and it makes my tests execution fail.

When I launch my tests whitout specifying any TestExecutionListener and I dig in Spring's logs, I can find :

`getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames : 
Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]:
    [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener,
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener,
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener,
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener,
    org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, 
    org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]`

So if I want to add my TestExecutionListener, I need to specify (in addition of the wanted implementation) all these default TestExectionListeners on my test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
    ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.class,
    MyCustomTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-ApplicationContext.xml" })
public class CabinetMembershipServiceImplTest {
     ...
}
```

Is there a way of just adding one (or more) TestExecutionListener, whithout having to explicitly declare each listener from the default configuration nor "overriding" the default ones ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode;

@TestExecutionListeners(value = { MyCustomTestExecutionListener.class }, mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way of just adding one (or more) TestExecutionListener,
>   whithout having to explicitly declare each listener from the default
>   configuration nor "overriding" the default ones?

Yes, this is possible since Spring Framework 4.1 and is clearly documented both in the Javadoc for `@TestExecutionListeners` and in the [Merging TestExecutionListeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-merging) section of the reference manual. The following example is taken directly from the reference manual.

```java
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(
    listeners = MyCustomTestExecutionListener.class,
    mergeMode = MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)
public class MyTest {
  // class body...
}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)